# ow safe is StringByAppendingString used in this way?

Tags: ios, string, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I am using Cocos2d 2.0 with ARC and that's my code:

```
hudAndPlayerFileName = @"hud";        
//...other code
hudAndPlayerFileName = [hudAndPlayerFileName stringByAppendingString:@"ST"];
```

I am wondering whether appending a string to another string will cause any memory leak or if, ARC, will deal with this. **Is there anything in this code that may lead to leaks?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You used string constants `@"hud"` as input and the return value is an autoreleased instance.*

Instead of create an immutable string `hudAndPlayerFileName`, you can use `NSMutableString`.

```
[hudAndPlayerFileName appendString:@"ST"];
```

This will append "ST" at end of the string contained in `hudAndPlayerFileName`

Comment: Fantastic, thank you @AnoppVaidya, so my previous way to create string was potentially causing leaks?

Comment: @mm24 No, it wasn't. It wouldn't even have caused leaks without ARC, since you used only string constants as input and the return value is an autoreleased instance.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks. I cosnider this comment as part of the answer and hence accept the answer. Thanks for your help.